Problem with JBOSS upgrade 7.3 to 7.4 - Spring
I got some problem for upgrade my Java Application and I don't know why.
My Java application is on JDK 1.8, i have no problem when i deploy my EAR on Jboss 7.3 but i got problem when I deploy the same EAR on Jboss 7.4
I use Spring release 5.3.26 , and since i deploy on Jboss 7.4 i got no problem in Server.log, but when i call my webservice every Spring beans , and Spring variable are Null
Do you have any ideas where I can look to resolve this issue?

My main pom with dependencies

  <properties>

    <springRelease>5.3.26</springRelease>
    <spring.batch.version>4.3.7</spring.batch.version>
    <org.aspectj.version>1.9.19</org.aspectj.version>
    <google.guava.version>31.1-jre</google.guava.version>
    <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
    <javaVersionJDK>8</javaVersionJDK>
    <jdk.vendor>redhat</jdk.vendor>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Pour auto deploy les ear dans son JBoss local -->
    <jboss.server>D:/otoolbox-sie/server/jboss-eap-7.4/standalone/deployments</jboss.server>


    <!-- Est redéfini pour le hors dossier -->
    <cia.application>CEA20</cia.application>

    <mvnAppli>/appli/CEA20</mvnAppli>
    <mvnData>${mvnAppli}/data</mvnData>
    <mvnLogConf>${mvnAppli}/conf</mvnLogConf>
    <mvnNAS>mntnfs/NAS_ECM</mvnNAS>
    <mvnNASMyCloud>mntnfs/NAS_CEA20</mvnNASMyCloud>


  
    <zipNameInDar />
    <!-- Pour les WS -->
    <dirNameInDar />
    <libInDar>target/${zipNameInDar}/lib</libInDar>
    <shellInDar>target/${zipNameInDar}/shell</shellInDar>
    <darNamePourWS>distribution-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</darNamePourWS>
    

  </properties>


  <scm>
    <connection>scm:tfs:${tfsAuthUser};${tfsAuthPwd}@${tfsUrl}::${sourcesPath}</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:tfs:${tfsAuthUser};${tfsAuthPwd}@${tfsUrl}::${sourcesPath}</developerConnection>
  </scm>

  <dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

      <!-- logback-classic embarque slf4j -->

      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Dependance pour les filtres logback -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- DB -->
      <!-- Voir https://www.oracle.com/fr/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html
        Chapitre :  What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions? -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>21.9.0.0</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- SL : couche échange -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.20</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- WS Client et serveur -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Spring -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Autres -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Pour le Common/SpringBatch Frame Work -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${springRelease}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Fin Common/SpringBatchFW -->

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <additionalConfig>
            <file>
              <name>.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs</name>
              <content>
                                <![CDATA[eclipse.preferences.version=1${line.separator}encoding/<project>=${project.build.sourceEncoding}${line.separator}]]>
              </content>
            </file>
          </additionalConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
          <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
   
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>tests</id>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
              <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
              <archive>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                <manifest>
                  <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>

          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              </manifest>
              <manifestEntries>
                <Compiled-Jdk>${javaVersion} ${jdk.vendor}</Compiled-Jdk>
              </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.9.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <archive>
              <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
              <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true
                </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true
                </addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
          <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.10.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>



Webservice implementation example :
@Service
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface = "fr.document.consultation.autogenerated.WSConsultationDocument")
public class WSConsultationDocumentImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements WSConsultationDocument {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("wsRecupererIndicateurReutilisation")
    private InvokedService<List<DocumentIndex>, List<DocumentDetail>> wsRecupererIndicateurReutilisation;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("wsRechercherLienDocumentDossier")
    private InvokedService<QstnRechercherLienDocumentDossier, RsttRechercherLienDocumentDossier> wsRechercherLienDocumentDossier;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("wsRechercherLienDocumentDnc")
    private InvokedService<QstnRechercherLienDocumentDnc, RsttRechercherLienDocumentDnc> wsRechercherLienDocumentDnc;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("wsRecupererCommentaireDocument")
    private InvokedService<QstnRecupererCommentaireDocument, RsttRecupererCommentaireDocument> wsRecupererCommentaireDocument;

    @Override
    public RsttRecupererIndicateurReutilisation recupererIndicateurReutilisation(
                    QstnRecupererIndicateurReutilisation qstnRecupererIndicateurReutilisation)
                    throws WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception, WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception {
        try {
            RsttRecupererIndicateurReutilisation retour = new RsttRecupererIndicateurReutilisation();
            retour.getDetailDocuments().addAll(wsRecupererIndicateurReutilisation
                            .execute(qstnRecupererIndicateurReutilisation.getIdentifiantDocuments()));
            return retour;
        } catch (ClaCliRuntimeException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception(exc);
        } catch (ClaCliMetierException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception(exc);
        }
    }

    /**

     * 
     * @param qstnRechercherLienDocumentDossier
     * @return RsttRechercherLienDocumentDossier
     * @throws WSClaCliMetierFault Exception metier
     * @throws WSClaCliRuntimeFault Exception technique a renvoyer au
     *             Webservice.
     */

    @Override
    public RsttRechercherLienDocumentDossier rechercherLienDocumentDossier(
                    QstnRechercherLienDocumentDossier qstnRechercherLienDocumentDossier)
                    throws WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception, WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception {
        try {
            return wsRechercherLienDocumentDossier.execute(qstnRechercherLienDocumentDossier);
        } catch (ClaCliRuntimeException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception(exc);
        } catch (ClaCliMetierException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception(exc);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Methode permettant de recuperer les liens entre un document et les dnc
     */
    public RsttRechercherLienDocumentDnc rechercherLienDocumentDnc(
                    QstnRechercherLienDocumentDnc qstnRechercherLienDocumentDnc)
                    throws WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception, WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception {
        try {
            return wsRechercherLienDocumentDnc.execute(qstnRechercherLienDocumentDnc);
        } catch (ClaCliRuntimeException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception(exc);
        } catch (ClaCliMetierException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception(exc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RsttRecupererCommentaireDocument recupererCommentaireDocument(
                    QstnRecupererCommentaireDocument qstnRecupererCommentaireDocument)
                    throws WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception, WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception {
        try {
            return wsRecupererCommentaireDocument.execute(qstnRecupererCommentaireDocument);
        } catch (ClaCliRuntimeException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliRuntimeFault_Exception(exc);
        } catch (ClaCliMetierException exc) {
            throw new WSClaCliMetierFault_Exception(exc);
        }
    }

}

I really try everything but found nothing , where i can start for find my problem issue ?

Still same problem... someone got an idea ?
